# How to keep &nbsp; non-breaking spaces in the visual editor?

Tags: tinymce, visual-editor, text, line-breaks

I often add `&nbsp;` between connecting words so they break down together to a new line in important text. Switching to visual tab then back to text tab removes these. What can I do to keep them and avoid TinyMCE removing them?

I found this but not sure how to apply it to WordPress: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/tinymce-removes-non-breaking-spaces

My ugly solutions would be using a different custom string between words__like__this then later replacing them to `&nbsp;` in PHP, before display. Or just typing it on the visual tab, which translates to `&amp;nbsp;` but then converting them with PHP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
function allow_nbsp_in_tinymce( $mceInit ) {
    $mceInit['entities'] = '160,nbsp,38,amp,60,lt,62,gt';   
    $mceInit['entity_encoding'] = 'named';
    return $mceInit;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'allow_nbsp_in_tinymce' );
```

Also see: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#entities

Any improvement suggestions?

Comment: Small improvement: you don’t have to repeat the existing entities (amp, lt, gt) in the config: `$mceInit['entities'] .= ',160,nbsp';`

Comment: By the way, many may find it useful to also preserve soft hyphens. Just add `173,shy` to the entities list.

Comment: Is there is a documentation on add_filter() or something? How to implement this in TinyMCE 4.x?

Comment: @Alph.Dev add_filter() is a wordpress function :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_filter/

Comment: Does this will work with elementor